# jQuery UI Resizable in TH

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html-table, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm trying to make a table with the th's of the header resizable.

Here you can see an example where I first try de resize with a div and then with a table (it works great). Then I try the resize with the th's of another table. Nothing happens.

http://jsfiddle.net/UVsKp/

Can the th's be resized using jquery UI??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with:

html:

```
<table id="tblResize2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="100px"><div>a</div></th>
            <th width="100px"><div>b</div></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>​
```

js:

```
$("#tblResize2 th div").resizable();
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work.  The Div can get smaller than the TH, and even if you try to correct for that, the table layout engine may decide that the column deserves to be wider than you ask it to be set to.

Answer (score 1):

I have done small tweak to force the size of the the during/after resize:

```
resize:function(event,ui){
      ui.helper.parent().css('width',ui.size.width+'px');
}
```